# Get the currently active branch using android repo tool

Tags: repo

I'm working in a multi-repo environment. Is it possible to get the currently active/working branch on each repo using android repo tool?

eg: say I have repos called repo1, repo2, repo3 and their respective active/working branches be branch1, branch2, branch3. I want to a result like the following.

repo1  | branch1
repo2  | branch2
repo3  | branch3

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"repo branch" pops up with all the branches highlighting current branches.